# Is there a way to set a request header using the JW Player

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, jwplayer

I am currently using the JW Player in a react app.

The videos I am trying to access are m3u8 playlist files that require a cookie to be sent in the header on each subsequent request.

**Issue :** So I can't just append the headers in the url as query params (e.g. https://somevideorul?cookie=somecookie).

**Question :** Is there a way to set headers with the request that the video player makes?  I can't seem to find anything in their docs that support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

```
 playlist: [{
    sources: [{
        file: 'video.m3u8',
        onXhrOpen: function(xhr, url) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('customHeader', 'customHeaderValue');
        }
    }]
}]
```

Comment: but there is no way to set an actual custom header unless you are working DRM content.

Comment: This does not work when playing on an iOS device, as it forces the native player which does not allow custom headers, unfortunately.